# C# run unit tests on previously compiled binaries

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm trying to optimise our pipelines and as a part of it I would like to reuse the built code to run unit tests as well as generate migrations script. For the migrations it works fine but the unit tests keep failing.

I have two separated projects - the app and the tests (app imports a few other library projects but that should not matter). In the build configuration they are both checked to be build, however, when I look to the output directory, there is no sign of the test project binaries.

Then when I run the `dotnet test` it fails with:

```
The argument /workdir/ProjectName.Tests/bin/Release/net7.0/ProjectName.Tests.dll is invalid. Please use the /help option to check the list of valid arguments.
```

The problem is that the binaries should actually live in the `/workdir/ProjectName/bin/ProjectConfigurationName/net7.0/` directory, but even that the tests dll is not there.

Here is excerpt of the pipeline to clarify what I try to do. Basically the idea is to not build twice the same project with the same configuration for different purposes. I have tried to call the `dotnet test` with the project name of the app as well as the tests but both fail.

```
CONFIGURATION=ProjectConfigurationName
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
dotnet restore -s https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
dotnet build $$PROJECT --configuration $$CONFIGURATION -p:Version=${VERSION}
dotnet test $$PROJECT --no-build --configuration $$CONFIGURATION
dotnet ef migrations script --no-build --idempotent --project $$PROJECT --context MyDbContext -o migrations.sql
```

Is it even possible or am I completely wrong here? Do I always have to build the tests project separately?

Answer (score 1):

Your intention is absolutely ok and I am using the same optimisation in my project.

There is only one thing missing in your implementation. You have to specify `output` folder and then both app and test will place there their dll.

So try this locally:

```
dotnet build --configuration Release --output ./release
dotnet test ./release/ProjectName.Tests.dll
```